# WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback gets hit but exits without executing the body

Tags: flutter, dart, callback

I have statements inside WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback method, but they are never executed.

```
DecorationVC

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      var productProvider =
          Provider.of<ProviderDetailsProvider>(context, listen: false);
      // var params = {};
      // if(widget.occasionId != null){
      // var params = {"occasion_id" : widget.occasionId};
      // }
      productProvider.fetchDecorations(
        params: widget.occasionId,
        fail: (error) => showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (builder) =>
                ResponseDialog(error.message, error.error, ResponseType.Fail)),
      );
    });
    // print(widget._itemId);
    // loadingData();
  }
```

In another program I have code like this

```
AddDecorationView(
           selectedDecor: provider.selectedDecoration,
           callback: () => callback(provider),
           )

.
.
.
.

void callback(ProviderDetailsProvider provider) async {
    Decorations decoration = await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DecorationVC(
              occasionId: provider.selectedOccasion == null
                  ? null
                  : provider.selectedOccasion.id),
        ));
    if (decoration != null) {
      provider.updateSelectedDecoration(decoration);
      _controller.move(provider.decorations.indexOf(decoration));
    }
  }
```

I think the problem is due to async statement in callback method.. but I dont know how to fix this... Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {}

Comment: I tried as you suggested... but it does not help... anyways thanks for the suggestion..